# How do I override maven clean goal to remove additional folders

Tags: maven

maven-clean-plugin removes target folder by default, but I would also like it to remove some additional application specific folders like 'logs', how should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the explanation provided in the plugin docs: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html